# Does this type of white PCB multi-pin connector have a specific name?

Tags: identification, connector

I sometimes come across white male headers mounted on PCBs as below:

[image: photo of connector on PCB]

Is there a specific name for this kind of connectors/headers/pins?

Comment: Provide measurements such as pitch when asking to identify connectors.

Comment: I've edited your question title to be more useful for search engine results.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is the PCB header for a single-wall wire-to-board connectors.

My [Indenticonn connector identification utility](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=single_wall_w2b_conn_2p5) identified it as made by many manufacturers, including:

- MANUF. - SERIES
- Adam tech - LHA LHS + MTA MTS (crimp)
- Bulgin - Buccaneer
- Hirose - DF1
- JAE - IL-G
- Molex - KK 2695 3022 4030 4094 4380 5045 5046 6373 6410 6471 7395 7478 7832 7880 35300 41662 42009 42225 42226 42227 42228 42375 42376 42377 42624 43009 45661 47053 47054 68301 87891 87897 91560 171856 171857
- Molex - KK 47053 + 254
- Molex - KK 5045 KK 5046 + KK 5051 51191
- OnShore - 2600-XX-S + 2510-XX
- OnShore - FL254B1V
- Samtec - LCW
- Sullins - SWR25X + SWH25X
- TE - EI 2.5m
- TE - MTA-100 + CTS-100 (1w crimp)
- TE - MTEI
- Wurth - WR-WTB 619

Yours in particular looks like a [MOLEX 0022232041](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/molex/0022232041/26671) because the back wall has the clearance for polarizing keys.

[image: 0022232041]

{Digikey}

If you're looking for the mate, it's a [Molex 0022013047](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/molex/0022013047/26435).

[image: 0022013047]

{Digikey}

Comment: Worth noting, that if ever looking to work with any wire-plug connectors, also get plenty of the female pins, correct gauge wire, good insulation stripper, and the correct crimping tool.  Tools may be expensive but are necessary.  There's nothing more frustrating than using "budget" tools which barely work.

Answer (score 4):

If those are 0.1 inch pitch, then they are possibly [Molex KK Interconnect System](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/family/kk) or [TE Connectivity MTA-100](https://www.te.com/usa-en/products/connectors/pcb-connectors/intersection/mta-100-mta-156-connectors.html?tab=pgp-story) or any of dozens of other brands/clones.

Comment: I believe with those bump "latches" they are KK396, slightly larger pitch.  They do all look very similar, really need to measure them to be sure.